# how to iterate and print logger xml object response data value we don't have java class for that object it's XSD and there is no toString()

Tags: java, xml, java-8, xsd, schema

Trying to iterate and print detailsResp data in loggers

I used streams code to print xml object schema file data to iterate and print in object data value in logger but every time it's printing hash code format value only. highly appreciate your response on my query

**sample response data** : GetObjectDetailsResponse detailsResp :

```xml
<ns2:GetObjectDetailsResponse xmlns="http://../../schema">
  <header>
    ...
  </header>
  <ns2:addressDetails>
    ...
  </ns2:addressDetails>
  <ns2:accountNumberList>
   <accountNumber>123456789</accountNumber>
   <accountType>Saving</accountType>
  </ns2:accountNumberList>
</ns2:GetObjectDetailsResponse>
```

```java
public class ExampleData {

  public ObjectDetails processData(GetObjectDetailsResponse detailsResp){
    value = processDetails(elementTag, index, detailsResp.getAccountNumberList());
    detailsResp.getAccountNumberList().stream().forEach(item -> logDebug("print getAccountNumberList value--->" + item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your XML is not **well-formed**. The *ns2* namespace prefix is not declared.

Comment: this code is working code I don't think ns2 format issue my only question how to print object data in loggers

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
Please edit your original question and provide the following:
(1) Well-formed XML sample. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your code attempt trying to implement it. 
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: Which is `item` class? What type of object is that one?

Answer (score 0):

You can rely on 3rd party libraries for logging purpose (like the `ToStringBuilder` from [apache commons-lang3](https://github.com/apache/commons-lang/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.java))

You can then have readable from with one line of code

```java
logDebug("print getAccountNumberList value--->" +
    ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(item));
```

You can also add XJC-plugin during XSD -> JAVA code generation like the [`-XtoString` XJC-plugin of jaxb-tools](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb-tools/wiki/JAXB2-ToString-Plugin)

Comment: Edited answer after re-reading the full title of the question